# Change span when text field changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with several text fields. I want to change a span tag when I write something in the field. Like this:

[image: Like this]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery `.change()` handler?  http://api.jquery.com/change/  Or keyup, or keypress, or many other handlers?

Comment: `("input").keyup(function() { $(this).closest("span").text(this.value); });`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `keyup` and then replace the `span` content with the `textbox` value.

```
<input id="test" type="text" />
<span id="content"></span>

$("#test").keyup(function() {
    $("#content").html($("#test").val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/

Edit:

You can also use `$(this).val()` as `pXL` has suggested.

```
$("#test").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#content").html(val);
});
```

Comment: You can also use `$(this).val()` or `this.value`

Comment: @pXL - true. Just went for speed. I will edit that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use jquery for this. For eg

```
<input type="text" id="mytext"/>
<span id="content"></span>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mytext").keyup(function(){
            $('#content').html($(this).val());
        })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use $.keyup() and update the html with input value.
**Demo:** [Working Demo](http://lightron.no-ip.org/tmp/49/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Regular typing updates.
    $("#input").keyup(function()
    {
        $("#output").html($(this).val());
    });

    // If pasted with mouse, when blur triggers, update.
    $("#input").change(function()
    {
        $(this).keyup();
    });

    // Any value loaded with the page.
    $("#input").keyup();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The lost focus is also an aproach,

html:

```
<input type="text" id="txa" value="123" />
<span>345</span>
```

jquery:

```
$('input[id=txa]').blur(function () {
    $(this).next("span").text($(this).val());
});
```

Glad to help.