# Change span when text field changes as you type

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I want text in the `span` field to change as the `input` field changes `live`.

So I have a `input` field

```
<input type="text">
```

and a `span` field

```
<span></span>
```

I want text in the `span` field to change as I type in the `input` field.

I know there's already a question like this that was asked [Change span when text field changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694731/change-span-when-text-field-changes). But what makes this question different is the changes should happen as you type i.e. `live`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a vanilla JavaScript version.

```js
var input  = document.querySelector("[type=text]"),
    output = document.querySelector(".output");

function keydownHandler() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

input.addEventListener("input", keydownHandler);
```

```html
<input type="text">
<span class="output"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am gonna use this one since i dont need jQuery here.

Comment: Thank you. When late to the party, it's better to bring vanilla.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple, use a `keyup` event.

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").keyup(function () {
    $("span").text(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<p><span></span></p>
```

In the latest browsers, you can use `oninput` event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @krimz You are welcome. Did you need only the vanilla JavaScript solution? You didn't mention that in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTML5 **[`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)** event, listen the event using **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```js
$('.input').on('input', function() {
  $('.span').text(this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
<br><span class="span"></span>
```

---

JavaScript solution with `input` event

```js
function change(val) {
  document.querySelector('.span').innerHTML = val;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="change(this.value)">
<br><span class="span"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!